# System.out.println doesn't work on a supplied Stream?

Tags: java, arrays, queue, consumer, supplier

I'm still new to Java, and especially new to Suppliers, but I can't figure out why I can't get any output from the following code:

```
final BufferedReader brLines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvFile));
final Supplier<Stream<LinkedList<String>>> procLines = () -> brLines.lines().map(elm -> processCSV(elm));

lineCount = Math.toIntExact(procLines.get().count());

System.out.println(lineCount); // This prints the correct amount of lines to the console.

final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(lineCount);

Stream<LinkedList<String>> listStream = procLines.get();
listStream.forEach((x) -> {
    System.out.println(x); // Why is there no console output here?
    outputText(() -> x); // Why is there no console output here either?

    ...
});
```

Here are some of the methods mentioned in this block

```
public static LinkedList<String> processCSV(String line) {  
    LinkedList<String> elms = new LinkedList<String>();
    char delimiter = ',';
    char quote = '"';

    String[] elmArray = splitCSVWithQuote(line, delimiter, quote).toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String elm : elmArray) {
        elms.add(elm);
    }

    return elms;
}
```

&

```
public static void outputText(Supplier sup) {
    System.out.println(sup.get());
}
```

Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've already consumed all the lines and creating a new `Stream` from a now-empty line-list doesn't give them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lineCount = Math.toIntExact(procLines.get().count());
```

`count()` is a terminal operation, it may traverse the stream to produce a result. After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and can no longer be used.

So you consumed all the lines of the file. So, the supplier can't give you again the stream since `BufferedReader` is now at the end-of-stream. That's why there is no output.

Comment: Yep, it's being consumed. I thought that `Supplier` provided new copies of the stream with each `.get()`, but I guess not.

Comment: The `Supplier` used by @Mbgm creates a new `Stream` each time, so that's not the problem. The problem is the same `BufferedReader` is used as the source. In other words, after the first stream the `BufferedReader` is now at the end-of-stream and the second stream has no elements to traverse.